# Problems using YouTubePlayerFragment, "the YouTubePlayerView is 0dp wide and 0dp high"

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am really struggling with using the `YouTubePlayerFragment` in my application. My implementation looks like this:

```
private void loadYouTubeVideo(final YouTubeViewHolder h, final Content content) {
        final YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = ((DetailActivity) getContext()).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fl_youtube, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
        final ViewTreeObserver observer = h.mRlYouTube.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(YOUTUBE_PLAYER_API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
                        if(!wasRestored) {
                            youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(content.getVideoId());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error initializing YouTube Video with id ");
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = ((DetailActivity) getContext()).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.remove(youTubePlayerFragment);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

The initialization is no problem, as a YouTubePlayer is displayed and the video is loaded. But it immediately stops after one second with the following message:

```
"YouTube video playback stopped due to the player's view being too small. The YouTubePlayerView is 0dp wide (minimum is 200dp) and 0dp high (minimum is 110dp)."
```

This is the XML layout with the `FrameLayout`, to which I add the `YouTubePlayerFragment` in the code above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fl_youtube"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:minHeight="110dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    >

</FrameLayout>
```

I have no idea why the YouTubePlayer pretends to have width and height 0. When I log the size of the FrameLayout, its height is 607 and its width is 1080 px. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: I have encountered this issue as well when using the YouTubePlayerView (not the fragment).

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Comment: I am using Youtube player view in recyclerview. I too got same issue. If you find solution, post the answer.

Comment: Any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me: add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` activity description like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

or just

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation">
```

[via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46173536/2404181)