# Screen orientation not working with youtubePlayerfragment

Tags: android, youtube-api

Currently working on android application which uses youtube api to show video. In this application I'm showing video in fragment using youtubeplayerfragment. When I click on full screen view orientation of screen changes to landscape mode in full screen view and when I click exit from full screen mode then screen remain still in landscape mode even try to rotate by rotating device and also each time screen orientation change video start from starting. How to retain video state on orientation change and how to solve my problem.

My code for youtube is here :

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    mYouTubePlayerFragment.initialize(Constants.YOUTUBEDEVELOPERKEY,
        new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {


                //on player full screen mode
                youTubePlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(true);
                youTubePlayer.setOnFullscreenListener(
                    new YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFullscreen(boolean b) {
                            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(b));
                        }
                    });

                //play video in the player
                if (!b) {
                    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(args.getString(Constants.VIDEOID));
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                } else {
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(
                YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                Log.d("FeedVideoFragment", youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
                youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), 0);
            }
        });
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.youtube_fragment,
        mYouTubePlayerFragment, MYYOUTUBEFRAGMENT).commit();

} else {

    mYouTubePlayerFragment.initialize(Constants.YOUTUBEDEVELOPERKEY,
        new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {


                //on player full screen mode
                youTubePlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(true);
                youTubePlayer.setOnFullscreenListener(
                    new YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFullscreen(boolean b) {

                        }
                    });

                //play video in the player
                if (!b) {
                    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(savedInstanceState.getString("videoId"));
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                } else {
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(
                YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                Log.d("FeedVideoFragment", youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
                youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), 0);
            }
        });
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MYYOUTUBEFRAGMENT);


}
```

Comment: You can verify in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer) if you are doing the right thing in implementing the screen orientation. This [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Streaming-Youtube-Videos-with-YouTubePlayerView) shows you on how to play video using the landscape mode in YouTube Player. So try to check it if it can help you. I also find this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012754) that is related about your issue.

Answer (score 2):

for saving video state use 
   `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` in your
   activity tag where your fragment is appearing eg:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

in your onFullscreen method check if player fullscreen set or not

```
@Override
       public void onFullscreen(boolean b) {
           Log.e("onFullscreen",""+b);
           if(b)
               fullscreen=1;
           else fullscreen=2;
       }
```

in your backpress bethod check if full screen is set then set to false

```
 @Override
           public void onBackPressed() {
               if(fullscreen==1)
               {
                   if(this.player!=null)
                       youTubePlayer.setFullscreen(false);
               }
               else
                   super.onBackPressed();
           }
```

i hope it helps you, sorry for my bad english

Comment: Just `android:configChanges="orientation"` works for me